# Difference between id and name spring attribute

Tags: java, spring

We can specify both `id` and `name` attribute for a spring bean, but what is the difference between them? In our project we only use id attribute like the following:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.foo.bar.MyBeanClass">
    <!-- Properties -->
</bean>
```

I'd like to unterstand the cases when I should use name attribute. I just have never come across it in the porjects.

Comment: Have you read the spring documentation?

Comment: @Jens Sure, I have. Why do we ever have to use multiple aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/clarifying-spring-framework-ids-and-names/) to have the full definition between the id and name.

Hope this helps

Comment: Web archived link of above https://web.archive.org/web/20160706184900/http://www.intertech.com:80/Blog/clarifying-spring-framework-ids-and-names/